# How to make more than one if state non case sensitive

Tags: html, input

Whenever I add a to.LowerCase to an else if statement it causes the whole statement to not work. Fixes Anyone?

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {

    ///monuments

        var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase(); ;
        if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {

            document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters";

        } else if (document.getElementById("ask").value == "how tall is the gateway arch") {

            document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "630 feet";
```

Comment: Why are you storing the value twice?

Comment: you can use `ask` variable in `else if` like `ask == "how ......"`, don't you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `document.getElementById("ask").value` again once assign it to ask

Try like this

```
var ask = document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase();
var info = "";
if (ask == "how tall are the pyramids") {
    info = "146.5 meters";
} else if (ask == "how tall is the gateway arch") {
    info = "630 feet";
}
document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = info
```